# Hibernate throws MultipleBagFetchException - cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, bag

Hibernate throws this exception during SessionFactory creation:

> org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

This is my test case:

**Parent.java**

```
@Entity
public Parent {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 // @IndexColumn(name="INDEX_COL") if I had this the problem solve but I retrieve more children than I have, one child is null.
 private List<Child> children;

}
```

**Child.java**

```
@Entity
public Child {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @ManyToOne
 private Parent parent;

}
```

How about this problem? What can I do?

---

**EDIT**

OK, the problem I have is that another "parent" entity is inside my parent, my real behavior is this:

**Parent.java**

```
@Entity
public Parent {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @ManyToOne
 private AnotherParent anotherParent;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 private List<Child> children;

}
```

**AnotherParent.java**

```
@Entity
public AnotherParent {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 private List<AnotherChild> anotherChildren;

}
```

Hibernate doesn't like two collections with `FetchType.EAGER`, but this seems to be a bug, I'm not doing unusual things...

Removing `FetchType.EAGER` from `Parent` or `AnotherParent` solves the problem, but I need it, so real solution is to use `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` instead of `FetchType` (thanks to [Bozho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203907/bozho) for the solution).

Comment: I would ask, what SQL query are you hoping to generate that will retrieve two separate collections simultaneously?  The kinds of SQL that would be able to achieve these would either require a cartesian join (potentially highly inefficient) or a UNION of disjoint columns (also ugly). Presumably the inability to achieve this in SQL in a clean & efficient manner influenced the API design.

Comment: @ThomasW These are the sql queries it should generate: `select * from master; select * from child1 where master_id = :master_id; select * from child2 where master_id = :master_id`

Comment: You can get a simillar error if you have more than one `List<child>` with `fetchType` defined for **more than one** `List<clield>`

Answer (score 690, accepted):

I think a newer version of hibernate (supporting JPA 2.0) should handle this. But otherwise you can work it around by annotating the collection fields with:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
```

Remember to remove the `fetchType` attribute from the `@*ToMany` annotation.

But note that in most cases a `Set<Child>` is more appropriate than `List<Child>`, so unless you really need a `List` - go for `Set`

##### Use with caution

Remember that using a `Set` **won't** eliminate the underlying **Cartesian Product** as described by [Vlad Mihalcea in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51055523/1657465), featured as **"The worst solution"**!

Comment: i'm using hibernate 3.6, i tried your suggest but the problem remains.

Comment: odd, it has worked for me. Did you remove the `fetchType` from the `@*ToMany` ?

Comment: oh, sorry, ok now works. However what is the reason of this problem? I used fetchtype EAGER a lot of times in equal situation without problem, why now i have this trouble? Thank you.

Comment: the problem is that the JPA annotations are parsed not to allow more than 2 eagerly loaded collection. But the hibernate-specific annnotations allow it.

Comment: The need for more than 1 EAGER seems totally realistic.  Is this limitation just a JPA oversight?  What are the concerns I should look for when having muliple EAGERs?

Comment: the thing is, hibernate can't fetch the two collections with one query. So when you query for the parent entity, it will need 2 extra queries per result, which is normally something you don't want.

Comment: This problem is exacerbated by JSF that only implements List in its UIData components. Even wrapping a Set in an ArrayList in JSF causes yet other problems, hence Lists linked directly to JPA is what JSF requires.

Comment: I only ran into this problem in my JUnit tests. It was unable to build EntityManagerFactory because of this MultipleBagFetchException. This answer solved it!

Comment: It'd be great to have an explanation as to why this resolves the issue.

Comment: to be honest, I don't know precisely - hibernate has some internal implementation details that make it possible. Probably different ways of handling (or simply validating?) the two annotations

Comment: @Webnet maybe this will make it clearer for you: https://github.com/introproventures/graphql-jpa-query/issues/2

Comment: Hibernate is a leaky abstraction that just does not work.

Comment: But I am trying to fetch them lazily, what's the problem of having two collections? Lazily means NOT at the same time, so what's the problem with two lists with no eager setted?

Comment: This doesn't work if you are fetching the lists with an Entity Graph

Comment: There's undefined behavior for fetching two Sets at the same time. Other users have different errors, but I was getting an StackOverflow error when hibernate was building a HashSet. I had to revert to List just to get it query calls to return.

Answer (score 330):

Simply change from `List` type to `Set` type.

##### Use with caution

This solution is not recommended as it **won't** eliminate the underlying **Cartesian Product** as described by [Vlad Mihalcea in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51055523/1657465), featured as **"The worst solution"**!

Comment: A List and a Set are not the same thing: a set does not preserve order

Comment: LinkedHashSet preserves order

Comment: This is an important distinction and, when you think about it, entirely correct. The typical many-to-one implemented by a foreign key in the DB is really not a List, it's a Set because order is not preserved. So Set is really more appropriate. I think that makes the difference in hibernate, though I don't know why.

Comment: I was having the same **cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags** but not because of annotations. In my case, I was doing left joins and disjunctions with the two `*ToMany`. Changing the type to `Set` solved my problem too. Excellent and neat solution. This should be the official answer.

Comment: If you want to preserver order you should use `SortedSet`.

Comment: @OndrejBozek But what order are you preserving? We are talking about a foreign key relation in the database. The DB can (and will) return the items in the order that happens to be most convenient to it. If you really want to control order, you need to add some ordering rule to the fetch query (not sure if/how it can be done with JPA), and maybe add some index field to sort on.

Comment: @StijndeWitt yes you can sort yout foreign key relation using `@OrderBy` or (in case of Hibernate) `@SortComparator` annotation. The you need to have `SortedSet`.It's quite common to have your associations sorted.

Comment: I liked the answer, but the million dollar question is: Why? Why with Set don't show exceptions? Thanks

Comment: I have a perfectly valid use case that was blowing up with this same exceptions when using List. I changed the code as Ahmad suggested and now I'm all "Set". :)

Comment: I had a similar problem, but I had `Collection` instead of `List`. Anyway, after I changed it to `Set`, the problem was gone. So, thanks!

Answer (score 212):

Considering we have the following entities:

[image]

And, you want to fetch some parent `Post` entities along with all the `comments` and `tags` collections.

If you are using more than one `JOIN FETCH` directives:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    left join fetch p.tags
    where p.id between :minId and :maxId
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("minId", 1L)
.setParameter("maxId", 50L)
.getResultList();
```

Hibernate will throw the infamous:

```
org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags [
  com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.fetching.Post.comments,
  com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.fetching.Post.tags
]
```

Hibernate doesn't allow fetching more than one bag because that would generate a Cartesian product.

### The worst "solution"

Now, you will find lots of answers, blog posts, videos, or other resources telling you to use a `Set` instead of a `List` for your collections.

**That's terrible advice. Don't do that!**

Using `Sets` instead of `Lists` will make the `MultipleBagFetchException` go away, but the Cartesian Product will still be there, which is actually even worse, as you'll find out the performance issue long after you applied this "fix".

### The proper Hibernate 6 solution

If you're using Hibernate 6, then you can fix this issue like this:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    where p.id between :minId and :maxId
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("minId", 1L)
.setParameter("maxId", 50L)
.getResultList();

posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select distinct p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.tags t
    where p in :posts 
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("posts", posts)
.getResultList();
```

As long as you fetch at most one collection using `JOIN FETCH` per query, you will be fine.

By using multiple queries, you will avoid the Cartesian Product since any other collection, but the first one is fetched using a secondary query.

### The proper Hibernate 5 solution

You can do the following trick:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select distinct p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    where p.id between :minId and :maxId
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("minId", 1L)
.setParameter("maxId", 50L)
.setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
.getResultList();

posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select distinct p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.tags t
    where p in :posts 
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter("posts", posts)
.setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
.getResultList();
```

> In the first JPQL query, `distinct` DOES NOT go to the SQL statement. That's why we set the `PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` JPA query hint to `false`.
>
> DISTINCT has two meanings in JPQL, and here, we need it to deduplicate the Java object references returned by `getResultList` on the Java side, not the SQL side.

By using multiple queries, you will avoid the Cartesian Product since any other collection, but the first one is fetched using a secondary query.

### There's more you could do

If you're using the `FetchType.EAGER` strategy at mapping time for `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` associations, then you could easily end up with a `MultipleBagFetchException`.

You are better off switching from `FetchType.EAGER` to `Fetchype.LAZY` since eager fetching is a terrible idea that can lead to critical application performance issues.

### Conclusion

Avoid `FetchType.EAGER` and don't switch from `List` to `Set` just because doing so will make Hibernate hide the `MultipleBagFetchException` under the carpet. Fetch just one collection at a time, and you'll be fine.

As long as you do it with the same number of queries as you have collections to initialize, you are fine. Just don't initialize the collections in a loop, as that will trigger N+1 query issues, which are also bad for performance.

Comment: Thanks for the shared knowledge. However,  `DISTINCT` is performance killer in this solution. Is there a way to get rid of `distinct`? (tried to return `Set<...>` instead, didn't help much)

Comment: Vlad, thanks for the help I find it really usuful. However, the issue was related to `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` (eventually I set it to 350). By the chance, do you know how to optimize nested relations? E.g. entity1 -> entity2 -> entity3.1, entity 3.2 (where entity3.1 / 3.2 are @OneToMany relations)

Comment: Can't we avoid Cartesian Product by using DISTINCT in one single jpql query with `Set`?

Comment: No, you can not. Think about it in terms of SQL. You cannot JOIN multiple one-to-many associations without generating a Cartesian Product.

Comment: What if comments has another collection that you want load with EAGER loading (List<CommentReviews>). I tried and had the same MultipleBagFetchException problem

Comment: You only get a `MultipleBagFetchException` if you issue `JOIN FETCH` twice in a JPQL query. However, the solution in this answer doesn't tell you to do that. If you read the answer carefully, you will see that you achieve the same goal using a single `JOIN FETCH` and an additional secondary query.

Comment: @VladMihalcea In your recommended solution, is there any point to assign posts = .getResultList() in your second query? It worked without this assignment in my case.

Comment: @İsmailYavuz It depends on the JIT implementation. If you return the `posts` variable from the currently executing method, then, if you don't reassign the `posts` variable, maybe the JIT will consider that call useless as it doesn't seem to have any side-effect.

Comment: @VladMihalcea If we have deep nesting like post has many postComments has many likes, Can we use list for first layer(postComments) and set for second layer(Likes) and dedup? This worked fine for me.  is there an issue? I mean dedup with with set will work for single one to many but not multiple so we can leverate with set in nexted fetches

Comment: If you are using spring data jpa and writing this query using custom implementation of repository, don't forget to add Transactional annotation to the method. @VladMihalcea Any reason why it gives LazyInitializationException if it's not annotatated with transactional?

Comment: You should always havd @Transactional on the service methods calling a Spring Data Jpa Repository. Not doing so is a terrible mistake.

Comment: Should the methods inside custom repository implementation also be annotated with Transactional? reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

Comment: Those are already transactional, but you want to set the Tx at the service layer so all repositories called from a service use the same Tx.

Comment: Is there any benefit for using additional secondary query and not `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`

Comment: Of course. The query is more obvious and doesn't have the IN clause limit issue.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you describe how to do this with the JPA entities, not just in plain hibernate project.

Comment: The `MultipleBagFetchException` is a Hibernate exception. Other JPA provides have other exceptions.

Comment: I was attempting to use this with `@NamedEntityGraph` annotated entity classes. It does not work, unless I remove the graph logic. Is there any merit to the entity graph technique?

Comment: I think it can work with entity graphs. I'll create a prototype when I'll have some time.

Comment: @VladMihalcea For me it's the same: Not working with  EntityGraph attributePaths, for now I'm using the Set aproach (I don't know if it creates cartesian product when used with Entity Graphs) do you think they do?

Comment: If you fetch two sibling Set associations using any strategy, you'll get a Cartesian Product. If the associations are related, like child amd grandchildren, then you won't get a Cartesian Product.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Then, it is safe to say that if I only have ONE attribute path in my EntityGraph, there's no way I'm getting a cartesian product, right?

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí JPA associations are fetched via LEFT or INNER joins. So, the only way to generate a Cartesian Product is the same as with plain SQL. After all, it all boils done to SQL. And, when using INNER and LEFT joins, the only way to generate a Cartesian Product is to generate two virtual tables (from intermediate joins) that cannot be associated by following the JOIN condition.

Comment: What if you had an additional collection on the `tags` object which you also wanted to initialise? Is it possible (or maybe unwise) to go another level deep?

Comment: Another best option is to use MyBatis for this kind of sceanario

Comment: @harshakumarReddy If you think it's that easy to fetch a graph of N-level relations using MyBatis, feel free to add a new answer and show it to us. I'm afraid your "best solution" will end up being more complex than using 2 JPQL queries and relying on the Persistence Context to bind the associations.

Comment: @VladMihalcea I was just suggesting hybrid approach not completely replacing hibernate entirely .  i remember that you have mentioned in your blog that for ManytoMany relationship its not good to use List and use Set instead because when we delete one child . all Childs will be deleted along with it and reinserted except the one deleted with is not efficient . can you shed more light on this,here you are saying Sets are not efficient

Comment: @harshakumarReddy Here, I'm not saying that Sets are not efficient. It's just that if you use Sets you don't get the exception, but you still get the Cartesian Product. You can also get the Cartesian Product with MyBatis and fetching a List of sibling children. Also, don't take one piece of advice from a context and generalize it for everything, as it's a bad idea. Use every piece of advice in its original context and you'll be fine.

Comment: Your answer is quite opinionated. It can make sense to do a cartesian product or it can be the worst solution, it depends on the data and use case. Additionally using List is not always the best options as you mentioned [it](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-favoring-sets-vs-bags/)  :)

Comment: @NicolasLabrot All of my answers are opinionated. That's because I've actually worked on the Hibernate ORM, so I'm very biased about it. As for that article, I suppose you missed the `The HHH-5855 issue was fixed in Hibernate 5.0.8, so another reason to update.` box on the article ;)

Comment: I did not miss it :), does it mean that List should be preferred over Set?

Comment: It depends. For embeddable, Set are better. For bidirectional one-to-many associations, it doesn't matter, but List are more versatile. For Many-to-Many, Sets are better. You can find a detailed explanation in my High-Performance Java Persistence book.

Comment: @VladMihalcea if i have bidirectional one-to-many can i switch from list to set and that's ok since you say it doesn't matter? Cartesian product will not be a mistake? however, are you saying that I can use the set but still download each collection separately? I have an object that has an on-to-many join and then each has five one-to-many joins. There are many records in the table, but there are single records that meet the join conditions. Is it better to loop through each of the collections separately for the first level join, or change to SET and concatenate all the joins?

Comment: In this example it seems to overwrite the first posts variable, how should we combine the results from each child collection on to the parent?

Comment: @VladMihalcea great answer how to do this with query annotations on repository methods in spring boot?

Comment: @JayD I'll blog about that in the future.

Comment: @VladMihalcea cheers mate looking forward to it

Comment: It's a good approach, using Spring Data JPA, in service call methods like invoice = invoiceRepository.finById(2L), then invoiceItemList = invoiceItemsRepository.findAllByInvoice(invoice); receiptList = receiptRepository.findAllByInvoice(invoice); then set all together.

Comment: Per the [Hibernate 6 migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html):

  Starting with Hibernate ORM 6 it is no longer necessary to use distinct in JPQL and
  HQL to filter out the same parent entity references when join fetching a child
  collection. The returning duplicates of entities are now always filtered by Hibernate.

  Which means that for instance it is no longer necessary to
  setQueryHints#HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH to false in order to skip the entity
  duplicates without producing a distinct in the SQL query.

Comment: @Philippe I updated the answer for Hibernate 6 too.

Comment: For those using a spring jpa repository, @VladMihalcea wrote a great blog post here: https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-data-jpa-multiplebagfetchexception/ His solution worked very well with findBy... queries and EntityGraph annotation.

Answer (score 186):

Add a Hibernate-specific @Fetch annotation to your code:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Child> childs;
```

This should fix the issue, related to Hibernate bug [HHH-1718](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1718)

Comment: @DaveRlz why subSelect solves this problem. I tried your solution and its working, but dont know how the problem was solved by using this ?

Comment: This is the best answer unless a `Set` really makes sense.  Having a single `OneToMany` relationship using a `Set` results in `1+<# relationships>` queries, where as using `FetchMode.SUBSELECT` results in `1+1` queries.  Also, using the annotation in the accepted answer (`LazyCollectionOption.FALSE`) causes even more queries to be executed.

Comment: FetchType.EAGER is not a proper solution for this.
Need to proceed with Hibernate Fetch Profiles and need to solve it

Comment: Every time I forget that annotation name I come back to this answer. ...Every time :)

Comment: Oh MAN! My controller was getting duplicate object list-nodes back from responses and this answer fixed it!  Thank you!  @DaveRlz   Im using JPA2.2 .

Comment: The two other top answers did not solve my problem. This one did. Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone know why does SUBSELECT fix it, but JOIN does not?

Comment: Now I get: `LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: xxxx  could not initialize proxy - no Session` error. I had to use `EAGER` or `LazyCollection` approach.

Comment: Worth mentioning this is **`org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode`** *(not `org.hibernate.FetchMode`)*

Comment: This should be tha accepted answer, it is not only easy to implement and understand, It is also really well performing!

Comment: I would like to integrate the comment from @SteveChambers in the answer but now the edit queue is full, as usual

Answer (score 49):

After trying with every single option describe in this posts and others, I came to the conclusion that the the fix is a follows.

In every XToMany place @`XXXToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`
and intermediately after

```
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
```

This worked for me

Comment: adding `@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` was enough

Comment: This is a Hibernate only solution. What if you are using a shared JPA library?

Comment: I'm sure you didnt mean to, but DaveRlz already wrote the same thing 3 years earlier

Comment: This is probably duplicate of the above answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8309458/3451846

Answer (score 17):

To fix it simply take `Set` in place of `List` for your nested object.

```
@OneToMany
Set<Your_object> objectList;
```

And don't forget to use `fetch=FetchType.EAGER`, It'll work.

There is one more concept `CollectionId` in Hibernate if you want to stick with list only.

##### Use with caution

Remember that you **won't** eliminate the underlying **Cartesian Product** as described by [Vlad Mihalcea in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51055523/1657465), featured as **"The worst solution"**!

Comment: Both recommendations you made are very bad in terms of performance.

Answer (score 7):

you can keep booth EAGER lists in JPA and add to at least one of them the JPA annotation **@OrderColumn** (with obviously the name of a field to be ordered). No need of specific hibernate annotations.
But keep in mind it could create empty elements in the list if the chosen field does not have values starting from 0

```
 [...]
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @OrderColumn(name="orderIndex")
 private List<Child> children;
 [...]
```

in Children then you should add the orderIndex field

Comment: this is a very underrated solution to this problem, deserves more attention.

Answer (score 3):

When you have too complex objects with saveral collection could not be good idea to have all of them with EAGER fetchType, better use LAZY and when you really need to load the collections use: `Hibernate.initialize(parent.child)` to fetch the data.

Answer (score 2):

We tried **Set** instead of **List** and it is a nightmare: when you add two new objects, **equals**() and **hashCode**() fail to distinguish both of them ! Because they don't have any id.

typical tools like Eclipse generate that kind of code from Database tables:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

You may also read [this article](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html?page=1) that explains properly how messed up JPA/Hibernate is. After reading this, I think this is the last time I use any ORM in my life.

I've also encounter Domain Driven Design guys that basically say ORM are a terrible thing.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was having nested *EAGER* fetches.

One solution is to set the nested fields to *LAZY* and use Hibernate.initialize() to load the nested field(s):

```
x = session.get(ClassName.class, id);
Hibernate.initialize(x.getNestedField());
```

Comment: I would like to set the Java syntax highlight but the edit queue is full now, as usual

Answer (score 1):

At my end, this happened when I had multiple collections with FetchType.EAGER, like this:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = className.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "myClass_id")
@JsonView(SerializationView.Summary.class)
private Collection<Model> ModelObjects;
```

Additionally, the collections were joining on the same column.

To solve this issue, I changed one of the collections to FetchType.LAZY since it was okay for my use-case.

Goodluck!
~J

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to make fetch=FetchType.LAZY and just add @Transactional(readOnly = true) to method where you get child

Answer (score 0):

Commenting both `Fetch` and `LazyCollection` sometimes helps to run project.

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

One good thing about `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` is that several fields with this annotation can coexist while `FetchType.EAGER` cannot, even in the situations where such coexistence is legit.

For example, an `Order` may have a list of `OrderGroup`(a short one) as well as a list of `Promotions`(also short). `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` can be used on both without causing `LazyInitializationException` neither `MultipleBagFetchException`.

In my case `@Fetch` did solve my problem of `MultipleBacFetchException` but then causes `LazyInitializationException`, the infamous `no Session` error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by annotating:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here's my 2 cents. I had the Fetch Lazy annotations in my Entity but I also duplicated the fetch lazy in the session bean thus causing a multiple bag issue. So I just removed the lines in my SessionBean

criteria.createAlias("FIELD", "ALIAS", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);  //REMOVED

And I used Hibernate.initialize on the list I wanted to retrieve after the List parent = criteria.list was called.
Hibernate.initialize(parent.getChildList());

Answer (score 0):

##### TLDR: Don't use EAGER. Always fetch things **only when you really need them**!

---

A lot of mentions here about `FetchType.EAGER` and I wanted to go a bit more into detail why this is a bad idea and on what to use alternatively. Hopefully after reading this you realize that really you should absolutely **NEVER** use `FetchType.EAGER`.

There is just no good reason to! It's a mayor pitfall that can bite you (or even worse: someone else) down the road. Imagine you chose FetchType.EAGER for a Student -> Teacher relation, because you think every time you need to fetch a Student you also need his Teachers. Now even if you are 100% sure you never need students without teachers **right now**, you simply can't foresee how requirements change. FetchType.EAGER violates the [Open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)! Your code is no longer **open for extension** - if later the need for loading Students without Teachers arise it's difficult do to that without reworking (and possibly breaking) existing code!

An even bigger problem you have is that you basically created an n+1 select problem for possible future queries, that (rightfully) already fetched another bag in the basic query. Let's say in the future someone wants to load all Students with their grades and there are 30000 of them. Since you told Hibernate to EAGER fetch all Teachers it has to do that. But since you already fetched another "bag" (the grades) within the same query this actually results in 30001 queries - for data that wasn't even needed in that scenario! The first query for loading all Students+Grades and then a separate query for each Student to fetch his teachers. Needless to say that this is horrendous for performance. In my opinion this is the sole reason for people to believe that "Hibernate is slow" - they just don't realize how incredible inefficient it **might** query stuff in some situations. You really have to be careful with 1:n relations.

3 Alternatives (manually fetch stuff when needed):

1. Use JOIN FETCH to fetch a collection. To stick with the example `SELECT stud FROM STUDENT stud JOIN FETCH stud.teachers` would do the trick. This will always fire a single query to fetch students AND teachers. Just be mindful to only fetch **one** collection that way (explanation would go too far for this answer).
2. If you use Spring-JPA you can use @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"teachers"}) to do the same.
3. You could call Hibernate.initialize(oneStudent.getTeachers()) with the Hibernate-proxy to fetch the relation manually. This will always create a separate query, so don't do it in a loop or you just created a n+1 select problem yourself.

---

Also one final tip in general: turn the logging for org.hibernate.SQL to DEBUG to see when/what queries are fired and make sure your local dev setup has a reasonable amount of data. When you test your code with only 2 students and don't check the queries that are fired you might miss something like that and end up having issues on real systems with more data.

Answer (score -5):

You could use a new annotation to solve this:

```
@XXXToXXX(targetEntity = XXXX.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

In fact, fetch's default value is FetchType.LAZY too.

Comment: JPA3.0 does not exist.