# Is it possible for Hibernate to fetch two levels of sets with one select?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I have three entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="a")
class A {

  @Id
  Long id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")    
  Set<B> bs;

  // ... other fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
class B {

  @Id
  Long id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "c_id")
  Set<C> cs;

  // ... other fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "c")
class C {

  @Id
  Long id;

  // ... other fields
}
```

When I use Criteria API from JPA to get given A, Hibernate first fetches just A, then for each A, all B's and finally for each B all C's.

Is it possible to force fetching with one select which is in theory possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't support well fetching multiple eager collections. Take a look here.

Btw do you really need those collection as eagerly loaded?

[Hibernate cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multiple-bags)

Comment: It doesn't really matter what kind of fetching I choose. It's instantly converted into another object graph to keep in memory.

Comment: I tried another approach and fetch using C as a root. But seems it doesn't work any faster. Probably because fetching is costly itself, and that's because of CLOB fields here, I bet. I'll leave it as it is and change fetching to LAZY. Need to live with this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like not possible without `internal iteration`.

In such cases i would like to suggest [Hibernate Native Sql query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html).