# JPA Hibernate Nested Objects

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

Basically I have 3 tables: COUNTRY, STATE and CITY.

in **Country.java:**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
private List<State> state = new Vector<State>();
```

in **State.java**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID")
private List<City> city = new Vector<City>();
```

JPA query looks like:

```
caEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT C FROM COUNTRY C 
        JOIN fetch C.STATE S JOIN fetch S.CITY").getResultList();
```

When I try to execute the query I get:

```
org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
```

I am sure my query is wrong, i am new to this, please appoint me to the right direction. I

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, i am getting org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags from the code above.

Comment: Why do you use lists for the collections?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is Hibernate can not fetch two bags `EAGER`ly. The quick solution would be to change the `List`s to `Set`s.

To read more:

- [Article 1](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/06/hibernate-exception-simultaneously.html)
- [Article 2](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_exception_simultaneously_fetch_multiple)

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multiple-bags) suggests a couple of other solutions.