# @OneToMany(EAGER) vs @LazyCollection(FALSE)&OneToMany(LAZY)

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-initialization

What is difference between codes?

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "siteesTypeSite", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Set<Sites> getSitees() {
    return sitees;
}
```

and

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "siteesTypeSite", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<Sites> getSitees() {
    return sitees;
}
```

As for me both of them makes similar result, but second case is more cleaner. If i mistook correct me please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) and @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996758/difference-between-lazycollectionlazycollectionoption-false-and-onetomanyfe)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference between the annotations is that `@OneToMany` is a pure JPA annotation. Whereas `@LazyCollection` is Hibernate specific.

So if you want your code to be portable across various JPA providers you should use JPA annotations.

## Update

To explain between those two annotation, consider the `OneToMany` relationship between `Department -> Employee`

***Case 1:***

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

if you fetch a `Department` object from the db using :

```
entityManager.find(Department.class, 1L);
```

following query gets fired to fetch the data

```
SELECT department0_.DEPARTMENT_ID AS DEPARTMENT_ID1_0_0_,
  department0_.DEPARTMENT_NAME    AS DEPARTMENT_NAME2_0_0_,
  department0_.LOCATION           AS LOCATION3_0_0_,
  employees1_.DEPARTMENT_ID       AS DEPARTMENT_ID3_1_1_,
  employees1_.EMPLOYEE_ID         AS EMPLOYEE_ID1_1_1_,
  employees1_.EMPLOYEE_ID         AS EMPLOYEE_ID1_1_2_,
  employees1_.DEPARTMENT_ID       AS DEPARTMENT_ID3_1_2_,
  employees1_.EMPLOYEE_NAME       AS EMPLOYEE_NAME2_1_2_
FROM DEPARTMENT department0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE employees1_
ON department0_.DEPARTMENT_ID   =employees1_.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE department0_.DEPARTMENT_ID=?
```

so it means it will fetch all the data in a single query at once.

***Case 2:***

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

similary if you fetch a Department object from the db using :

```
entityManager.find(Department.class, 1L);
```

following queries gets fired to fetch the data :

```
SELECT department0_.DEPARTMENT_ID AS DEPARTMENT_ID1_0_0_,
  department0_.DEPARTMENT_NAME    AS DEPARTMENT_NAME2_0_0_,
  department0_.LOCATION           AS LOCATION3_0_0_
FROM DEPARTMENT department0_
WHERE department0_.DEPARTMENT_ID=?

SELECT employees0_.DEPARTMENT_ID AS DEPARTMENT_ID3_1_0_,
  employees0_.EMPLOYEE_ID        AS EMPLOYEE_ID1_1_0_,
  employees0_.EMPLOYEE_ID        AS EMPLOYEE_ID1_1_1_,
  employees0_.DEPARTMENT_ID      AS DEPARTMENT_ID3_1_1_,
  employees0_.EMPLOYEE_NAME      AS EMPLOYEE_NAME2_1_1_
FROM EMPLOYEE employees0_
WHERE employees0_.DEPARTMENT_ID=?
```

So to summarize, in first case since the `FetchType` is `EAGER` `Employees` are fetched eagerly along with `Department` in a single `JOIN` query.

And,

In second case, `Employees` are fetched with `Department` but since the `FetchType` is `LAZY` a seperate query will be fired to fetch `Employees`. And if you remove `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` `Employees` wont be fetched at all until you access `Employees` on `Department` instance.

Comment: Is this answer for question? **What is difference between codes?**

Comment: in what context you need the difference? @Sergii

Comment: Is it joke? If you apply first code in your program and other part in you program. which result should be? @Sergii _As for me both of them makes similar result_

Comment: I think first case is example of **overengineering**. But i need some confirmations (i never used **LazyCollection** before, who knows, possible it provides process something with better performance or something else). First code part i have  found in article but appeared doubt.

Comment: I can't get import annotation @LazyCollection in my project I am running Wildfly 12.0.   Running of this way: D:\Software\wildfly-12.0.0.Final\bin 
standalone -b 0.0.0.0 --debug --server-config=standalone.xml -Dee8.preview.mode=true

Comment: @eatSleepCode Why are you using both `@LazyCollection` and `fetchType` in your second case! shouldn't it be a demonstration of using one over the other?