# NHibernate. “Cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags” with multiple Fetch

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

First of all I should say that I did not familiar with Nhibernate at all, but project that I work with using this ORM instead of EF, I don't know why.
As I know this bug can be fixed by splitting queries, but I do not have any idea how to make this by using NHibernate.
Here is the query:

```
query = query.Where(c => c.Trade.Id == tradeId);
query = query
  .Fetch(lot => lot.Items)
  .Fetch(lot => lot.Documents)
  .Fetch(lot => lot.TradeLotApplications)
  .FetchMany(lot => lot.Customers)
  .ThenFetch(cus => cus.Customer);
lots = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Are you using IList or Set in entity collections?

Comment: Change to set and try again.

Comment: Seemed like this will not work  as I cannot convert type ISet to IList.

Comment: I mean `IList` to `ISet`, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5865605/1486443