# Why can't I use two lists on the same entity class using FetchType.EAGER

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, mapping, many-to-one

I am implementing an entity class which has 2 relations one-to-many but I can't use `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` for the two list.
I should use `FetchType.LAZY` for both.

Is there a solution to use EAGER for both?

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="fournisseur",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade={ CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE} )
private List<Carburant_entree> carburant_entrees; 

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade={ CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE} )
private List<Users> theusers;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multiple-bags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Set` in place of `List`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="fournisseur",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade={ CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE} )
private Set<CarburantEntree> carburantEntrees; 

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade={ CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE} )
private Set<Users> users;
```

Please, follow the Java Naming Conventntion.

Comment: thank you but can i use LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) ?

Comment: @AliBouslama I never use it

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can be achieve by Annotating the relationship with

```
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
```

in your case it should be.

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy="fournisseur",cascade={ CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE} )
private List<Carburant_entree> carburant_entrees; 

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade={ CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE} )
private List<Users> theusers;
```

Comment: when i try to use @lazycollection anotation it doesn't recognize that annotation
what can i do??

Comment: FetchType has limitations on how much FetchType.EAGER can be used. which is loading two lists as EAGER. wherein @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) will allow you to load any number of Lists as EAGER.

Comment: Forgot to mention that `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` is hibernate specific. so if you are not using hibernate then this wont work. in that case you can go for @v.ladynev solution.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg i am using hibernate but lazycollection is not recognized

Comment: Which version of hibernate you are using? I am using `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` in my application with hibernate version 4.3.6.FINAL