# Hibernate HQL Join Fetch returns duplicate rows

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

**ProcessSolution Entity :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="process_solution")
public class ProcessSolution implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="process_id", columnDefinition="INT(10) UNSIGNED")
    private Integer processId;

    @Column(name="process_name", length=120, nullable=false)
    private String processName;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    //@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    //@Fetch(FetchMode.Select)
    @JsonIgnore
    @CollectionTable(name="process_solution_step", 
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="process_id"),
        foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_process_solution_step_process_id")
    )
    @Column(name="solution_step", length=200, nullable=false)
    private List<String> processSolutionSteps = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name="category_id", columnDefinition="INT(10) UNSIGNED",nullable=false,
        foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_process_solution_category")
    )
    private Category category;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="process_solution_employee",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="process_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="emp_id",columnDefinition="INT(10) UNSIGNED")},
        foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_process_employee_process_solution_process_id"),
        inverseForeignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_process_employee_employee_emp_id")
    )
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();

    // Getters/Setters
}
```

And I'm Executing `HQL` Query in **DAO as:**

```
@Override
public ProcessSolution getProcessSolution(Integer processId) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    final String GET_PS = "SELECT ps FROM ProcessSolution ps JOIN FETCH ps.processSolutionSteps JOIN FETCH ps.employees WHERE ps.processId = :processId";
    //ProcessSolution processSolution = session.get(ProcessSolution.class, processId);
    ProcessSolution processSolution = ( ProcessSolution ) session.createQuery(GET_PS)
                                        .setInteger("processId", processId).uniqueResult();
    session.close();
    return processSolution;
}
```

My Problem is I'm Getting `ElementCollection` i.e. `processSolutionSteps` repeated **(Multiple Rows)**.
So I changed it From **`List<>`** to **`Set<>`**, now I'm getting correct result but its **order is not preserved**.

What I have tried:

1. For `Set` I have tried `LinkedHashSet` but problem still persist.
2. @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4335514/3425489)
3. @Fetch(FetchMode.Select) from another **SO** source

Any Idea how to solve this problem.

**Updated :**
**Sample Data :**

```
**process_solution**

+---------------+----------------+
|  process_id   |  process_name  |
+---------------+----------------+
|      3        |  process 1     |
+---------------+----------------+

**process_solution_step**

+---------------+----------------+
|  process_id   |  solution_step |
+---------------+----------------+
|      3        |    step 1      |
+---------------+----------------+
|      3        |    step 2      |
+---------------+----------------+
```

If I print Process Solution Steps I get the result as

1. step 1
2. step 1
3. step 2
4. step 2

If I print Employee Lenth I got correct result.

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: Sets don't have any order. Your List, as it is mapped, doesn't guarantee any order either. To avoid duplicates and have a guaranteed order, you need an OrderColumn. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html

Comment: @JBNizet, I will try `@OrderColumn` and let you know

Comment: @JBNizet, Is my HQL query ok ?

Comment: @JBNizet `@OrderColumn` annotation gave me last row only

Comment: Most probably because all your rows have the same value for that order column. It must contain the index of the row in the list.

Comment: @JBNizet,  I added another entry i.e. ProcessSolution, for ProcessSolutionSteps it created another column `processSolutionSteps_ORDER` for now it is working. I will update you if problem occurs..

Comment: thanks a  lot for working solution,

Comment: But I don't understand why this happened ?

Comment: @JBNizet ,  could you please tell me tips for improving hibernate and what should I do to  avoid common mistakes done ?

Comment: Read the Hibernate user guide, from top to bottom. Practice.

Comment: ok, I will go thorough it

Comment: @JBNizet Can you help me please, for this https://stackoverflow.com/q/45103580/3425489

Comment: @JBNizet I have another problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45234946/3425489

Comment: @JBNizet please help me for https://stackoverflow.com/q/45234946/3425489