# HQL query returning Empty Resultset

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have this **HQL query** which returns me an **Empty Resultset** :

```
FROM MeetingSchedule ms JOIN FETCH ms.client JOIN FETCH ms.employees JOIN FETCH ms.parts 
WHERE ms.meetingId = :meetingId;
```

If I execute **SQL Query** gives me result

```
select * from meeting_schedule where meeting_id = ?;
```

**How to debug this query?**

**What will be the cause for Empty Resultset ?**

**PS:**

**SQL Query** is just to inform you that my **MeetingSchedule** is not null, I can post generated **SQL Query** here if you want.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Those are 2 different queries. In HQL you are using JOINS while in SQL not. Do the comparision of results of EXACT the same queries. Answer is ratjher simple - some of relations are missing causing join to fail, excluding given row in result.

Equivalent of SQL you have shown is

```
FROM MeetingSchedule ms WHERE ms.meetingId = :meetingId;
```

I bet that result will not be empty.

Comment: ofcourse these are, by using 2nd **(SQL Query)** I just want to say that my **`MeetingSchedule`** is not null, there is problem with **join**, How to debug that ?

Comment: I dont care about `MeetingSchedule`. What I want to tell you is that joins are causing results to be null. Just execute proper SQL and see yourself

Comment: Can you tell me, please, what is the possibility that  joins are causing results to be null ?

Comment: @shantaram_t that's how **inner** joins work in HQL and in SQL. You're asking for meeting schedules which have the given ID AND which have a client AND which have employees AND which have parts. Note that inner join fetch isn't even valid JPQL. HQL accepts it, but JPQL doesn't. Use `left join fetch` instead and a `select distinct ms` clause, and your query will be valid JPQL and return the meeting schedules you expect.

Comment: @JBNizet ty, this solved my problem, this was bcoz `org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists`,

Comment: @JBNizet And Antoniossss Can I convert this HQL to get whole `MeetingSchedule` and **IDs and Names** from `Client`, `Part`, `Employee`, like **`Projections`**

Comment: Sure. Just adapt you select clause: `select distinct ms, client.id, client.name, part.id, part.name ...`. But if you just select distintc ms, you can just navigate through the object graph to have the information.

Comment: What I will get in result then, I don't want result in `List<Object [] >`, since it is very tedious to change in view

Comment: @shantaram_t insteed of wasting your and others time in pointless arguing, you could just execute plain sql with inner joins and either convince yourself that you are wrong all the time (finally) or prove to us that we were wrong from the beginning and joins are not the issue.

Comment: @Antoniossss I just asked 2nd question related to my query, JB Nizet's suggestion solved my problem