# How to use OneToMany Association in more than one table

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jpql

[image]

I am trying to join three tables with my model class.Here is my model classes.

Users.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
public String username;
public String password;
public Integer privid;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pid")
private Set<Privillages> priviJoin;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "actid")
private Set<Actions> actionJoin;



public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@Column(name = "username")
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
@Column(name = "password")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name = "privid")
public Integer getPrivid() {
    return privid;
}
public void setPrivid(Integer privid) {
    this.privid = privid;
}


public Set<Privillages> getPriviJoin() {
    return priviJoin;
}

public void setPriviJoin(Set<Privillages> priviJoin) {
    this.priviJoin = priviJoin;
}

public Set<Actions> getActionJoin() {
    return actionJoin;
}

public void setActionJoin(Set<Actions> actionJoin) {
    this.actionJoin = actionJoin;
}

public Users() {
}
}
```

And Privillages.java,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "privillages")
public class Privillages implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Integer id;

@Column(name = "pname")
public String pname;


@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "pid", referencedColumnName = "privid")
public Users pid;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getPname() {
    return pname;
}
public void setPname(String pname) {
    this.pname = pname;
}

public Users getPid() {
    return pid;
}
public void setPid(Users pid) {
    this.pid = pid;
}

public Privillages(){
} 
}
```

And Actions.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "actions")
public class Actions implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Integer id;


@Column(name = "actname")
public String actname;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "actid", referencedColumnName = "privid")
public Users actid;



public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getActname() {
    return actname;
}

public void setActname(String actname) {
    this.actname = actname;
}

public Users getActid() {
    return actid;
}

public void setActid(Users actid) {
    this.actid = actid;
}
public  Actions(){
}
}
```

My repository containing following code,

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u.*,p.*,a.* FROM users u "
            + "INNER JOIN privillages p ON u.privid = p.pid "
            + "INNER JOIN  actions a ON u.privid = a.actid", 
 nativeQuery=true)
Set<Users> findByUsername();
```

My controller action is,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/joinResult", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView joinResultShow(Model model)
        {
            model.addAttribute("joinData",userRepo.findByUsername());
            ModelAndView viewObj = new ModelAndView("fleethome");
            return viewObj;
        }
```

And my view fleethome is like,

```
<table>
        <th> Username </th>
        <th> Privillage </th>
        <th> Action </th>
            <tr th:each="message : ${joinData}">

              <td th:text="${message.username}"></td>
              <td><span th:each="privi : ${message.priviJoin}"
                 th:text="${privi.pname}"></span></td>
              <td><span th:each="action : ${message.actionJoin}"
                 th:text="${action.actname}"></span></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

I am trying to join Privillages and Actions with my main model Users. Users-Privillages have one to many. And also Users - Actions also have one to many. When I joined Users with Privillages it working good. I successfully joined two table.

Now I also need to join Actions class with Users. I am trying to displaying one column from each Model classes. When I implemented the procedure that I follow previously for joining Users-Privillages is not working here, when I added one more table.

I am getting the error like,

```
 There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
 Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "message.pname" (fleethome:65)
```

How can I join the additional one table with my previous join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't do that without model entity changes.
If i got you right, you want to get your entity class with multiple related collections initialized from db. But this can't work as is in your case because `MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`. It is basically the same problem of multiple collections with `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`. Easy fix would be to change  `Collection<Privillages>` to `Set<Privillages>` or same for `Actions` if you can.
[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multiple-bags)

---

As for `Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "message.pid.username"` the actual reason is that you are trying to work with `joinData` as if it is some database table record, but instead you should work with it like you would with java classes. Because you already got `Set<User> joinData` from hibernate. Can try something like

```
<tr th:each="message : ${joinData}">

    <td th:text="${message.username}"></td>
    <td><span th:each="privi : ${message.priviJoin}"
              th:text="${privi.pname}"></span></td>
    <td><span th:each="action : ${message.actionJoin}"
              th:text="${action.actname}"></span></td>

</tr>
```

If you want same output like in the image you provided, you can try:

```
<div  th:remove="tag" th:each="message : ${joinData}">
    <div th:remove="tag" th:each="privi : ${message.priviJoin}">
        <div th:remove="tag" th:each="action : ${message.actionJoin}">
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${message.username}"></td>
                <td th:text="${privi.pname}"></td>
                <td th:text="${action.actname}"></td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I will explore more on this basis. I am new to spring and spring data JPA,I am trying to join multiple,as you already understood.I will read more about this Collection , Set, And will try on those. And thank you for your response sir.

Comment: I tried the same with set. But this time I got a error in view page that -  "There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "message.pid.username" (fleethome:52)".  I also edited my question after my updation of code. How I can fix this issue?? Can you look on my code and error if you have time??

Comment: @MJacob Try `model.addAttribute("joinData",userRepo.findByUsername());
        return "fleethome"` instead of creation of a new model. Or put `viewObj.addAttribute("joinData",userRepo.findByUsername());` one line lower instead. I think you need to set `joinData`  on` viewObj` model you returning

Comment: Ok..I will try.But My problem is still there , that the error mentioned in comment also in editted question. What method I need to follow to solve this issue?? did you see my error?

Comment: @MJacob  your error is part of the thymeleaf and says that you cant use `message.pid.username` like you use it because `joinData` is `Set<Users>`  so `message` is `Users` and there is no `pid` field in `Users`

Comment: Yaa. already tried like {message.username},{message.pname},{message.actname} which are the atributes in those three tables. But that set again showing "Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "message.pname". How i can handle these displaying properties in view page??

Comment: Currently I only accessing username ,that is column of my main model. How I can handle the remaining?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156523/discussion-between-mjacob-and-varren).

Comment: I updated with my new code.And can you look on my updates? It is working only for the set basis. I need to display the all data as mentioned in the image on top.Currently I used native query.Can you look on updated code? What I need to follow for getting in the given structure?