# JPQL multiple join fetch returns error "cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags"

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am studying with Spring Data JPA.

I have a problem dealing with JPQL. I god three entities.

```
public class Cheat implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cheat_seq", length = 10)
    private Long cheatSeq;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cheat", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<CheatGoodVote> goodVote;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cheat", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<CheatBadVote> badVote;

    // skipped.
}
```

and others are the entities that is mapped to above entity.

```
public class CheatGoodVote {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="vote_seq", length=10)
    private Long voteSeq;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="cheat_fk", referencedColumnName="cheat_seq")
    public Cheat cheat;

    // ..skipped
}
```

Two entities are nearly the same each other.

```
public class CheatBadVote {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="vote_seq", length=10)
    private Long voteSeq;

    @Column(name="ip_address", nullable=false)
    private String ipAddress;

    @Column(name="reg_date", nullable=false)
    private Date regDate;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="cheat_fk", referencedColumnName="cheat_seq")
    public Cheat cheat;

}
```

And when I call JPQL **"@Query("SELECT c FROM Cheat c JOIN FETCH c.goodVote JOIN FETCH c.badVote WHERE SIZE(c.goodVote) <= :voteCnt")"**,

It returns errors:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [com.aibiigae1221.skyQuiz.data.entity.Cheat.goodVote, com.aibiigae1221.skyQuiz.data.entity.Cheat.badVote]
    at org.hibernate.loader.BasicLoader.postInstantiate(BasicLoader.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.<init>(QueryLoader.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 103 common frames omitted
```

I want to get *Cheat*, *CheatGoodVote*, *CheatBadVote* entitie together.
Is the error come from jpql problem? or my entity mapping is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multiple-bags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be framework related bug. Depends on your hibernate version.

Consider this issue, looks like yours [LINK](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10648)

### Cartesian product

Be aware that join fetching both colections you will end up with [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of both. For more information about problem itself and solutions go [HERE](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2012/08/fetch-join-and-cartesian-product-problem.html)