# Duplicate data in the child object

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 2.1 with spring data jpa and hibernate

```
@Entity
public class Factories{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "factories_id_seq", sequenceName = "factories_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "factories_id_seq")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "factory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Machines> machines = new ArrayList<>();

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<String> emails = new HashSet<>();

}
```

In my machine entity, i have an equals and hashCode method.

Query done

```
SELECT distinct f from Factories f "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH f.machines "
        + "Left JOIN FETCH f.emails "
        + "Left JOIN FETCH f.cities "
        + "where f.id=:id
```

I tried with distinct and without

My factory with id 1

have 3 machine and 3 emails

Instead of loading factory with 3 machines and 3 emails, I get 9 machines. In the database there are only 3.

It's like a cartesian product is done.

Any idea

Answer (score 1):

You just hit the `MultipleBagFetch` issue with Hibernate or any JPA. And yes you are right, what are you seeing is the result of `Cartesian Product` but that's business as usual. There are more posts on SO discussing over the same. To resolve your issue you have 3 options:

## a) Split the fetch into two JOIN queries

```
SELECT distinct f from Factories f "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH f.machines "
        + "Left JOIN FETCH f.cities "
        + "where f.id=:id

SELECT distinct f from Factories f "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH f.machines "
        + "Left JOIN FETCH f.emails "
        + "where f.id=:id
```

## b) Use Hibernate specific solutions:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
```

### OR

```
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multiple-bags)

Comment: @Fetch is hibernate, hot JPA standard: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Fetch.html