# LazyInitializationException occurs when trying to access collection of loaded entity

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I'm getting a LazyInitializationException when I'm trying to access the `permissions` collection of my `User` object. Exception message:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: dev.teamnight.nightweb.core.entities.User.permissions, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

This are the important parts of the User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User {

    // [...] Other variables
        @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_groups",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "groupId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
            )
    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    private List<UserPermission> permissions;

    // [...] Getter Setter

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
        /**
         * Check for User
         * UserPermission has yes or no/neutral, no resolves to true, no/neutral to no, UserPermissions override all GroupPermissions, if no go to GroupPerms
         * (Groups are sorted by priority, highest priority first, all permissions to one ArrayList)
         * GroupPermission true allows, neutral ignores, false denies
         */
        UserPermission userPerm = this.permissions.stream()
                .filter(perm -> perm.getName().equals(permission))
                .filter(perm -> perm.getType() == Permission.Type.FLAG)
                .filter(perm -> perm.getAsBoolean())
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);

        if(userPerm != null) {
            return true;
        }

        boolean allow = false;

        List<GroupPermission> groupPermissions = new ArrayList<GroupPermission>();

        this.groups.forEach(group -> {
            groupPermissions.addAll(group.getPermissions().stream().filter(perm -> perm.getType() == Permission.Type.FLAG).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        });

        for(GroupPermission perm : groupPermissions) {
            Tribool bool = perm.getAsTribool();

            if(bool == Tribool.TRUE) {
                allow = true;
            } else if(bool == Tribool.FALSE) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return allow;
    }
```

UserPermission.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_permissions", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"userId", "name"}))
public class UserPermission extends Permission {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    private User user;

}
```

UserHelper.java:

```
    public <T extends User> T getByUsername(String username, Class<T> type) {
        Session session = this.factory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Query<T> query = session.createQuery("FROM " + type.getCanonicalName() + " U WHERE U.username = :username", type);
        query.setParameter("username", username);

        T user = query.uniqueResult();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        return user;
    }
```

I'm calling getByUsername() to receive the user from the database and then later I try to access the permissions using User.hasPermission("testperm") and then the exception above happens.

**EDIT**: Mention there is another association, so FetchType.EAGER or @Fetch(FetchMode.join) lead to another exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options to fix the [LazyInitializationException](https://thorben-janssen.com/lazyinitializationexception/). You could use multiple JOIN FETCH clauses to initialize all required associations, or you could perform a query for each required association. I explained both in great details in my recent article about the [2 best options to fix Hibernate's MultipleBagFetchException](https://thorben-janssen.com/fix-multiplebagfetchexception-hibernate/).

**Option 1 - Multiple JOIN FETCH clauses**

For this option, you need to change the type of your to-many associations to `Set` instead of `List`. This prevents `MulitpleBagFetchException` when fetching multiple to-many associations.
In the next step, you can use a query that JOIN FETCHes all required association, e.g.:

```
SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.permissions LEFT JOIN FETCH u.groups
```

This is a good approach if the product created by your query is small. In this case, that means you only select a few `User` entities, and your `permissions` and `groups` associations only contain a few entities.

**Option 2 - Multiple queries**

Hibernate ensures that within a `Session`, each database record gets mapped to only 1 entity object. So, no matter how often you select the `User` entity with id 1, Hibernate will always map it to the same `User` entity object. You can use that initialize multiple associations without struggling with the `MultipleBagFetchException`. 
In this example, you could perform 2 queries. The 1st one gets `User` entities and initializes the `permissions` associations. The 2nd one gets `User` entities and initializes the `groups` associations.

```
SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.permissions
SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.groups
```

Answer (score 0):

I think (I'm not sure) changing the fetch type to EAGER would help, you can see the differences in the documentation.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
@OrderBy("name ASC")
private List<UserPermission> permissions;
```

Or use this annotation if you have multiple @*toMany

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)

and remove fetch from the @*toMany. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-throws-multiplebagfetchexception-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multipl))

Comment: This leads to an error because I have two OneToMany Lists in my User class.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-throws-multiplebagfetchexception-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multipl)
you can use this link to solve the problem. I hope this would help!

Answer (score 0):

You may have run into the ancient problem that some people have solved with the Open-Session-In-View pattern or `session-per-request` pattern:

> You can extend the scope of a Session and database transaction until
>   the "view has been rendered". This is especially useful in servlet
>   applications that utilize a separate rendering phase after the request
>   has been processed. Extending the database transaction until view
>   rendering, is achieved by implementing your own interceptor. However,
>   this will be difficult if you rely on EJBs with container-managed
>   transactions. A transaction will be completed when an EJB method
>   returns, before rendering of any view can start. See the Hibernate
>   website and forum for tips and examples relating to this Open Session
>   in View pattern.

[quote source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/5/html/hibernate_core_reference_guide/transactions)

See also the same documentation (or [Hibernate documentation Ch. 13 on Transactions and Concurrency](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html) for this and other patterns like:

`session-per-conversation`

NB.: I have seen these patterns work quite well in practice but some consider them an anti-pattern, read up on the arguments and alternatives (like the already mentioned in other answers: `join fetch`) in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/)

P.S.: There is also extensive documentation from Hibernate on [Fetching Strategies and performance](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/5/html/hibernate_core_reference_guide/performance#performance-fetching)