# EntityManagerFactory failed to initialize

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

guys
I have this entity :

```
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;



@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "dob")
    private String dob;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Card> cards;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Address> addresses;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Order> orders;
}
```

```
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Client> clients;
}
```

```
import lombok.*;
import ru.mialyshev.demo.demo.model.enums.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;



@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "delivery_type")
    private Delivery delivery;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "order_status")
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "payment_status")
    private PaymentStatus paymentStatus;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "payment_type")
    private PaymentType paymentType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<OrderProduct> orderProducts;

}
```

```
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;



@Entity
@Table(name = "cards")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Card {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "card_number")
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "validaty_date")
    private String validatyDate;

    @Column(name = "card_owner")
    private String owner;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;
}
```

```
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;



@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "postal_code")
    private String postalCode;

    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "house_number")
    private String houseNumber;

    @Column(name = "apartament_number")
    private String apartamentNumber;

    @Column(name = "is_saved")
    private boolean isSaved;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Order> orders;
}
```

And some service for him, which added new database entries. When I'm start this app (Spring boot + Spring Data), i am getting the following exception :

```
Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [ru.mialyshev.demo.demo.model.Client.cards, ru.mialyshev.demo.demo.model.Client.orders]
2020-12-28 16:15:09.040  WARN 12012 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [ru.mialyshev.demo.demo.model.Client.cards, ru.mialyshev.demo.demo.model.Client.orders]
```

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [ru.mialyshev.demo.demo.model.Client.cards, ru.mialyshev.demo.demo.model.Client.orders]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at ru.mialyshev.demo.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [ru.mialyshev.demo.demo.model.Client.cards, ru.mialyshev.demo.demo.model.Client.orders]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [ru.mialyshev.demo.demo.model.Client.cards, ru.mialyshev.demo.demo.model.Client.orders]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadQueryDetails.generate(AbstractLoadQueryDetails.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails.<init>(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.BatchingLoadQueryDetailsFactory.makeEntityLoadQueryDetails(BatchingLoadQueryDetailsFactory.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.<init>(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.<init>(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.EntityLoader.<init>(EntityLoader.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.EntityLoader.<init>(EntityLoader.java:30) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.EntityLoader$Builder.byUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.EntityLoader$Builder.byPrimaryKey(EntityLoader.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractBatchingEntityLoaderBuilder.buildNonBatchingLoader(AbstractBatchingEntityLoaderBuilder.java:30) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.BatchingEntityLoaderBuilder.buildLoader(BatchingEntityLoaderBuilder.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createEntityLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2610) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createEntityLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2632) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.generateDelayedEntityLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4384) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.LazyIndexedMap.lockedComputeIfAbsent(LazyIndexedMap.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.LazyIndexedMap.computeIfAbsent(LazyIndexedMap.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityLoaderLazyCollection.getOrBuildByLockMode(EntityLoaderLazyCollection.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getLoaderByLockMode(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4375) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createLoaders(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4362) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4337) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 21 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong? Before that, I wrote an application with similar functionality and everything worked fine. Now, in the new application, these are the errors.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-throws-multiplebagfetchexception-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multipl

Comment: please show your configuration files to get an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` at your `@OneToMany` relations. That means Hibernate would try to fetch them together with the related entities using a JOIN, with multiple relations in place, that would be way to huge. Generally it's not advisable to use `EAGER` fetching, better user `LAZY` fetching and build custom queries where they are needed. Check out https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/ on this topic. Maybe Bootify.io may help you as well to create the database model.