# MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities

**RegisteredProgram**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EntityListeners(RegisteredProgramAuditListener.class)
public class RegisteredProgram extends Auditable<String> {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "registeredProgram", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Trainer> trainerList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "registeredProgram", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Official> officialList;
}
```

**Trainer**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(TrainerAuditListener.class)
@Entity
public class Trainer extends Auditable<String> {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "REGISTERED_PROGRAM_ID", nullable = false)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private RegisteredProgram registeredProgram;

    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private Boolean isDeleted = false;
}
```

**Official**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(OfficialAuditListener.class)
@Entity
public class Official extends Auditable<String> {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "REGISTERED_PROGRAM_ID", nullable = false)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private RegisteredProgram registeredProgram;

    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private Boolean isDeleted = false;
}
```

Basically I have entities with many to one relationship with `RegisteredProgram`, (Trainer-RegisteredProgram, Official-RegisteredProgram). Now I have a service which already achieves my requirement, to fetch a registered program by id and I should only include all the `Trainer` and `Official` with **isDeleted** false. See the service below:

**Service**

```
@Override
public RegisteredProgramRequestDto getRegisteredProgramDto(Long id) {
    RegisteredProgram registeredProgram = registeredProgramRepository.getOne(id);
    RegisteredProgramRequestDto registeredProgramRequestDto = programRegistrationMapper
            .registeredProgramToRequestDto(registeredProgram);
    registeredProgramRequestDto.setOfficialDtoList(
            registeredProgramRequestDto.getOfficialDtoList()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(officialDto -> !officialDto.getIsDeleted())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
    registeredProgramRequestDto.setTrainerDtoList(
            registeredProgramRequestDto.getTrainerDtoList()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(trainerDto -> !trainerDto.getIsDeleted())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
    return registeredProgramRequestDto;
}
```

Now, I tried to use `@Query` and `@EntityGraph` so I can be able to get the desired output using only **a single query**.

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface RegisteredProgramRepository extends JpaRepository<RegisteredProgram, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<RegisteredProgram> {

    @Query("select rp from RegisteredProgram rp join rp.officialList rpos join rp.trainerList rpts where rp.id = :id and rpos.isDeleted = false and rpts.isDeleted = false")
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"officialList", "trainerList"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    RegisteredProgram getByIdNotDeleted(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

**Updated Service**

```
@Override
public RegisteredProgramRequestDto getRegisteredProgramDto(Long id) {
    RegisteredProgram registeredProgram = registeredProgramRepository.getByIdNotDeleted(id);
    return programRegistrationMapper
            .registeredProgramToRequestDto(registeredProgram);
}
```

But after implementing it, i am encountering the error below:

> org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [com.tesda8.region8.program.registration.model.entities.RegisteredProgram.officialList, com.tesda8.region8.program.registration.model.entities.RegisteredProgram.trainerList]

I already searched through stackoverflow and bumped into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-throws-multiplebagfetchexception-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multipl?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I still can't get my query to execute properly. Any ideas on how should I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular fix for solving `MultipleBagFetchException` is change `List` typed fields on `Set` typed, like this:

```
...
public class RegisteredProgram extends Auditable<String> {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "registeredProgram", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Trainer> trainerList = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "registeredProgram", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Official> officialList = new HashSet<>();
    ...
}
```

For more details see: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-how-to-avoid-hibernates-multiplebagfetchexception/

**Note:** Remember about `equals` and `hashcode` for `Set` data structure and avoiding Lombok & Hibernate pitfalls(https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/). Please pay attention for 'Avoid @Data' topic, because I see you are using that combination, that combination can produce unexpected behavior!

Comment: After changing from `List` to `Set` and removing `@Data` from the entities and replaced it instead with `@Getter` and `@Setter` solved everything. Thank you man!

Comment: This doesn't solve cartesian product. See here: https://allaroundjava.com/hibernate-cartesian-product-problem/ what you can do is to add this to fetch selects independently @org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)