# How to fetch multiple lists with EntityGraph

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I've been too much time trying to do something that seems simple at first look:

Let's say I have a `Store` entity with two `@OneToMany` relationships:

```java
@Entity
public class Store {

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store")
    private List<Foo> foos;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store")
    private List<Bar> bars;

}
```

I want to fetch both lists with the same query. I want to use Entity Graphs, because I need to decide in execution time which children I want to fetch.

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"foos", "bars"})
Store findByName(String name);
```

This causes:

```
MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags.
```

I don't want to use `Set` instead of `List`, because the purpose of this approach is to avoid the N+1 query problem **and** the Cartesian product problem (the entity hierarchy is much bigger than the example), so no `lazy fetching` or changing `List` into `Set` do help in this case.

Also, the first answer proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970) does not work with Entity Graphs.

Any ideas?

Comment: `I need to decide in execution time which children I want to fetch` You will still be having different method per each unique combination of elements in `attributePaths` right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate throws MultipleBagFetchException - cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-throws-multiplebagfetchexception-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multipl)

Comment: @JavaLearner Yes, one different query per use-case

Comment: @silentsudo No. That doesn't apply to Entity Graphs.

Comment: Have you explored the option of fetching directly from `Foo` and `Bar` based on FK id to store?

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí Do you have any update for this problem?

Comment: I realize that you explicitly say that you don't want to consider lazy-loading the collections, but in your question / explanation, you say that part of the purpose of this is to avoid the N+1 problem. I assume that by this, you mean that you have a collection of Store objects, and you need to load Foo or Bar from each item. This can be avoided by using the BatchSize() annotation. Then if you specify a BatchSize -> 5000 then you only execute a query to load Foo (or Bar) every 5000 elements. (I realize this is a slight simplification, but only slight...)

Comment: You should try Perism which doesn't have these problems.

Answer (score 17):

The main goal of the [Entity Graph](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityGraph.html) is to improve the runtime performance when loading the entity's related associations and basic fields. It is solving N+1 problem. Hibernate loads all the graph in one select query and then avoids fetching association with more `SELECT` queries.

It needs to be understood that by the current implementation, Entity Graph generating for execution only **one** `SELECT` query, because there is no possibility to specify other Fetch Mode than defined by default [FetchMode.JOIN](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/FetchMode.html#JOIN) for all attribute paths in the graph.

It is perfect for relations like `ManyToOne`, `OneToOne`, and for single `OneToMany` because all of them can be loaded by one query.

But if an entity has multiple `OneToMany` relations it is a problem to load full data by one query, because of Cartesian join. If we have 50 `Store` rows associated with 20 `Foo` and 10 `Bar` rows, the final result set will contain 10_000 records (e.g., 50 x 20 x 10). It is terrible for performance!

This is the main reason for `MultipleBagFetchException`. Hibernate protects you from Cartesian join.

So we can load two collections only thru separated select queries.

For now, Entity Graph does not support such loading.

There is a pending not resolved [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10485?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true) and [discussion](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/jpa-entity-graphs-and-hibernate-fetch-fetchmode-select-mode/1928).

The same thing is also with [Fetch Profiles](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching-profile). Only [FetchMode.JOIN](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/FetchMode.html#JOIN) is currently supported.

See good explanation [The best way to fix the Hibernate MultipleBagFetchException](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/)

**Solution 1: two JPQL queries**

Instead of executing a single query that fetches two associations, we can execute two JPQL queries:

```java
public interface StoreRepository extends JpaRepository<Store, Long> {

    default List<Store> findStoresByNameWithCollections(String name) {
        List<Store> stores = findByName(name);
        if (stores != null && !stores.isEmpty()) {
            stores = loadStoreBars(stores);
        }
        return stores;
    }

    @Query(value = "select DISTINCT st from Store st LEFT JOIN FETCH st.foos where st.name like :name")
    @QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false" )}, forCounting = false)
    List<Store> findByName(String name);

    @Query(value = "select DISTINCT st from Store st LEFT JOIN FETCH st.bars where st in (:stores)")
    @QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false" )}, forCounting = false)
    List<Store> loadStoreBars(List<Store> stores);
}
```

`hibernate.query.passDistinctThrough` JPA query hint we used to instruct Hibernate to prevent passing the JPQL DISTINCT keyword to the underlying SQL query. Unique of parent entities will be performed on the server-side.

Generated queries:

```sql
--Parent entity with Foos collection
    select
        store0_.id as id1_36_0_,
        foos1_.id as id1_15_1_,
        store0_.name as name2_36_0_,
        foos1_.store_id as store_id2_15_1_,
        foos1_.store_id as store_id2_15_0__,
        foos1_.id as id1_15_0__ 
    from
        store store0_ 
    left outer join
        foo foos1_ 
            on store0_.id=foos1_.store_id 
    where
        store0_.name like ?

--Bars collection
    select
        store0_.id as id1_36_0_,
        bars1_.id as id1_5_1_,
        store0_.name as name2_36_0_,
        bars1_.store_id as store_id2_5_1_,
        bars1_.store_id as store_id2_5_0__,
        bars1_.id as id1_5_0__ 
    from
        store store0_ 
    left outer join
        bar bars1_ 
            on store0_.id=bars1_.store_id 
    where
        store0_.id in (
            ? , ?
        )
```

**Solution 2: [FetchMode.SUBSELECT](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetchmode-subselect)**

```java
@Entity
public class Store {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Foo> foos;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Bar> bars;
}
```

Hibernate is going to avoid the N + 1 query issue by generating a single SQL statement to initialize all collections for all `Store` entities that were previously fetched. Instead of passing all entity identifiers, Hibernate simply reruns the previous query that fetched the `Store` entities.

Generated queries:

```sql
--Parent entities
    select
        store0_.id as id1_36_,
        store0_.name as name2_36_ 
    from
        store store0_ 
    where
        store0_.name like ?

--Foos collection
    select
        foos0_.store_id as store_id2_15_1_,
        foos0_.id as id1_15_1_,
        foos0_.id as id1_15_0_,
        foos0_.store_id as store_id2_15_0_ 
    from
        foo foos0_ 
    where
        foos0_.store_id in (
            select
                store0_.id 
            from
                store store0_ 
            where
                store0_.name like ?
        )

--Bars collection
    select
        bars0_.store_id as store_id2_5_1_,
        bars0_.id as id1_5_1_,
        bars0_.id as id1_5_0_,
        bars0_.store_id as store_id2_5_0_ 
    from
        bar bars0_ 
    where
        bars0_.store_id in (
            select
                store0_.id 
            from
                store store0_ 
            where
                store0_.name like ?
        )
```

**Solution 3: FetchMode.SUBSELECT + EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD**

When the `javax.persistence.loadgraph` property is used to specify an entity graph, attributes that are specified by attribute nodes of the entity graph are treated as `FetchType.EAGER` and attributes that are not specified are treated according to their specified or default FetchType.

Collections that are not specified in graph will use their own Fetch Mode.

```java
public interface StoreRepository extends JpaRepository<Store, Long> {
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"foos"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    List<Store> findByName(String name);
}

public class Store {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store")
    private List<Foo> foos;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Bar> bars;
}
```

Generated queries:

```sql
    select
        store0_.id as id1_36_0_,
        foos1_.id as id1_15_1_,
        store0_.name as name2_36_0_,
        foos1_.store_id as store_id2_15_1_,
        foos1_.store_id as store_id2_15_0__,
        foos1_.id as id1_15_0__ 
    from
        store store0_ 
    left outer join
        foo foos1_ 
            on store0_.id=foos1_.store_id 
    where
        store0_.name=?

    select
        bars0_.store_id as store_id2_5_1_,
        bars0_.id as id1_5_1_,
        bars0_.id as id1_5_0_,
        bars0_.store_id as store_id2_5_0_ 
    from
        bar bars0_ 
    where
        bars0_.store_id in (
            select
                store0_.id 
            from
                store store0_ 
            left outer join
                foo foos1_ 
                    on store0_.id=foos1_.store_id 
            where
                store0_.name=?
        )
```

**Solution 4, [BatchSize](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-batch)**

However, although `@BatchSize` is better than running into an N+1 query issue, most of the time, Solution 1 and Solution 2 is a much better alternative since it allows you to fetch all the required data with minimum queries count.

Batch size is tricky. It is a coefficient to determine the count of collections for loading in one query, it is not an exact collections count.

For example if you have 20 parent records and collection with batch size 50, hibernate will generate 1 query for loading parent entities and then 2 queries for initializing collections(First: 12 collections and Second:8 collections).

```java
public class Store {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @BatchSize(size = 50)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store")
    private List<Foo> foos;

    @BatchSize(size = 50)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store")
    private List<Bar> bars;
}
```

Generated queries:

```sql
--Parent entities
    select
        store0_.id as id1_36_,
        store0_.name as name2_36_ 
    from
        store store0_ 
    where
        store0_.name=?

--Bar collections
    select
        bars0_.store_id as store_id2_5_1_,
        bars0_.id as id1_5_1_,
        bars0_.id as id1_5_0_,
        bars0_.store_id as store_id2_5_0_ 
    from
        bar bars0_ 
    where
        bars0_.store_id in (
            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
        )

    select
        bars0_.store_id as store_id2_5_1_,
        bars0_.id as id1_5_1_,
        bars0_.id as id1_5_0_,
        bars0_.store_id as store_id2_5_0_ 
    from
        bar bars0_ 
    where
        bars0_.store_id in (
            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
        )

--Foo collections
    select
        foos0_.store_id as store_id2_15_1_,
        foos0_.id as id1_15_1_,
        foos0_.id as id1_15_0_,
        foos0_.store_id as store_id2_15_0_ 
    from
        foo foos0_ 
    where
        foos0_.store_id in (
            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
        )


    select
        foos0_.store_id as store_id2_15_1_,
        foos0_.id as id1_15_1_,
        foos0_.id as id1_15_0_,
        foos0_.store_id as store_id2_15_0_ 
    from
        foo foos0_ 
    where
        foos0_.store_id in (
            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
        )
```

Comment: @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) Won't work with entity graph. If you use entity graph it will use join instead of select. https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/jpa-entity-graphs-and-hibernate-fetch-fetchmode-select-mode/1928