# Micronaut Data: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException

Tags: hibernate, micronaut, micronaut-data

I am ussing micronaut-data framework to a app that store server emails.

I have a entity EMAILDB, that store the email in sql tables.

in this entity i have many to many relations with email address:

```
@ManyToMany
List<AddressDB> destinatarysTo;
@ManyToMany
List<AddressDB> destinatarysCC;
@ManyToMany
List<AddressDB> destinatarysCCO;
```

And i have a method that give me this emails in the email repository:

```
@Join(value = "destinatarysTo", type = Join.Type.LEFT_FETCH)
@Join(value = "destinatarysCC", type = Join.Type.LEFT_FETCH)
@Join(value = "destinatarysCCO", type = Join.Type.LEFT_FETCH)
public List<EmailDB> findByFolder(FolderDB folder);
```

But when i use it:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
```

What is the correct way?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate throws MultipleBagFetchException - cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-throws-multiplebagfetchexception-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multipl)

Comment: I am not sure, the solution proposed in that question is use @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
, but micronaut is not a complete jpa or hibernaute ORM, it always fetch lazy. for avoid n+1 query

Comment: The root of the problem here is that you try to fetch several collections simultaneously. The main goal of this exception is notify you about potential problem with Cartesian Product. As it's suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51055523/6277104) answer: *As long as you fetch at most one collection using JOIN FETCH, you will be fine.*

Comment: thanks i don't find the way for solution , and i remove joins fetch

Comment: As workaround you can replace `List<AddressDB>` by `Set<AddressDB>`, if Cartesian Product is not important for this case.