# Hibernate: many-to-one relationship with "Table per concrete class with unions"

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, union, hibernate-mapping

In the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate, Second Edition", section 6.2 "Table per concrete class with unions" (p.120) it describes one way to map class inheritance.

The entities are:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BillingDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = Constants.ID_GENERATOR)
    protected Long id;

    @NotNull
    protected String owner;
    // ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class CreditCard extends BillingDetails {

    @NotNull
    protected String cardNumber;

    @NotNull
    protected String expMonth;

    @NotNull
    protected String expYear;

    // ...
}
```

The SQL created to select from the tables is:

```
select
    ID, OWNER, EXPMONTH, EXPYEAR, CARDNUMBER,
    ACCOUNT, BANKNAME, SWIFT, CLAZZ_
from
    ( select
        ID, OWNER, EXPMONTH, EXPYEAR, CARDNUMBER,
        null as ACCOUNT,
        null as BANKNAME,
        null as SWIFT,
        1 as CLAZZ_
    from
        CREDITCARD
    union all
    select
        id, OWNER,
        null as EXPMONTH,
        null as EXPYEAR,
        null as CARDNUMBER,
        ACCOUNT, BANKNAME, SWIFT,
        2 as CLAZZ_
    from
        BANKACCOUNT
) as BILLINGDETAILS
```

So far the table schema is clear to me.

Now, I want to extend this schema. I want to add a new entity, `Purchase`, so that there are many `Purchase`s for every `BillingDetails`.

Is it possible to implement it while keeping the basic schema of the `BillingDetails` hierarchy?

If it's possible, can you describe the tables of the extended schema?

I'm not necessarily interested in a way to describe the schema by Hibernate annotations/XML (in case that it cannot be mapped by Hibernate annotations/XML), but in the basic table structure and related SQL that can describe such a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is one-to-many relation `BillingDetails 1 - * Purchase`. There are tons of examples for this over the internet.

On a database level you would need a foreign key (FK), i.e., a reference from `Purchase` table to `BillingDetails`. Meaning that in `Purchase` you have a column "billing_details_id" which should point to the existing billing details record.

It is possible to achieve this without changing the `BillingDetails` but you might want to update `BillingDetails` to let Hibernate know that it is many-to-one to `Purchase`.

Comment: But there is no actual `BillingDetails` table in this schema. It's only a temporary table defined in the `select` query.

Comment: got your point, this seems like your case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923841/how-do-you-map-two-abstract-inheritancetype-table-per-class-entities-with-a-onet
but not too nice, maybe this gives you some ideas to search more

Comment: I can't see how it's related to my case. What is the actual structure of the `Purchase` table that you are suggesting?