# Hibernate: Found two representations of same collection

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, collections, annotations

I have a `Spring MVC` project, with `Hibernate` annotation entity mapping. Up until now the database was created alright, saving new objects went on without problems. Until I added a new entity class.

The error happens when I try to save a `User` with a Date field changed (`last_login`) like this:

```
 User u = userService.get(userDetails.getUsername());
 u.setLast_login(new Timestamp((new java.util.Date()).getTime()));
 spService.save(u.getRegisterPoint());
 spService.save(u.getWorkSalePoint());//Because of another error
 userService.update(u);
```

where:

```
@Override
public boolean update(User user) {
    try {
        session().update(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I tried adding cascades to relations, tried without any of them(they were working fine, without the class).

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id_u;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_login")
    private Timestamp last_login;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_register_point", referencedColumnName = "id_sp")
    SalePoint registerPoint;

    @Transient
    private int registerPoint_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_work_sp", referencedColumnName = "id_sp")
    SalePoint workSalePoint;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

**SalePoint.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SALEPOINTS")
public class SalePoint {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_sp")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id_sp;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "registerPoint")
    private Set<User> registeredClients;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "workSalePoint")
    private Set<User> workers;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "salePoint")
    private Set<Order> orders;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**Status.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATUSES")
public class Status {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_s")
    private int id_s;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "status")
    List<Order> orders;

    public Status() {}

    public int getId_s() {
        return id_s;
    }

    public void setId_s(int id_s) {
        this.id_s = id_s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Status:" + name;
    }

}
```

**StackTrace:**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Found two representations of same collection: pl.spot.dbk.points.server.hib.SalePoint.workers; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: pl.spot.dbk.points.server.hib.SalePoint.workers

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Found two representations of same collection: pl.spot.dbk.points.server.hib.SalePoint.workers; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: pl.spot.dbk.points.server.hib.SalePoint.workers

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Found two representations of same collection: pl.spot.dbk.points.server.hib.SalePoint.workers; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: pl.spot.dbk.points.server.hib.SalePoint.workers
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
root cause

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Found two representations of same collection: pl.spot.dbk.points.server.hib.SalePoint.workers; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: pl.spot.dbk.points.server.hib.SalePoint.workers
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:690)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:793)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:664)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.save(Unknown Source)
pl.spot.dbk.points.web.LoginController.prepareLoginSuccessForm(LoginController.java:42)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: pl.spot.dbk.points.server.hib.SalePoint.workers
org.hibernate.engine.Collections.processReachableCollection(Collections.java:176)
org.hibernate.event.def.FlushVisitor.processCollection(FlushVisitor.java:60)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:124)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:84)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:78)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:161)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:49)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.save(Unknown Source)
pl.spot.dbk.points.web.LoginController.prepareLoginSuccessForm(LoginController.java:42)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

I tried various options, and read almost all posts about it here, but they were about plusframework, xml mappings, or other.

Can you help?

Comment: Can you add stack trace

Comment: I knew that I'd forget something :) @Real: Stack trace added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pinpointed the source of the problem. It was the id's of, well, everything. Initially I had  this in `Hibernate's`file `import.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO roles (id_r,"name") VALUES (1,'user');
INSERT INTO roles (id_r,"name") VALUES (11,'sell');
INSERT INTO roles (id_r,"name") VALUES (111,'admin');
INSERT INTO salepoints (id_sp,"name") VALUES (0,'HQ');
INSERT INTO salepoints (id_sp,"name") VALUES (1,'INTERNET');
INSERT INTO users (...,id) VALUES (...,0);
```

Both `SalesPoint` id's were dubbed by `roles`(INTERNET), and new initial `user`(HQ). After changing to:

```
INSERT INTO roles (id_r,"name") VALUES (1,'user');
INSERT INTO roles (id_r,"name") VALUES (11,'sell');
INSERT INTO roles (id_r,"name") VALUES (111,'admin');
INSERT INTO salepoints (id_sp,"name") VALUES (5,'HQ');
INSERT INTO salepoints (id_sp,"name") VALUES (10,'INTERNET');
INSERT INTO users (...,id) VALUES (...,50);
SELECT setval('public.hibernate_sequence', 200, true);
//It will work with every value
//above the maximum from the id inserted.
```

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this message when there are referential integrity problems in the database (which isn't really the first thing you'd think of). In my case the problem was that items in the collection referred to rows in another table which had been removed.

If possible it's probably simplest to ensure your database is set up with referential indexes to ensure that this can't happen.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

The problem is hibernate `session` detects the same `collection` twice in the same `session` when you call `update()`.

**Solution:**

Insure that there is no duplicate setters and getters in your entity and Instead of using `update()` just use `merge()`.

Comment: Another try @Real: I tried the `merge()` function but it didn't work. Follow up question: How does hibernate determine identical collections ?

Comment: @Cornelius that problem is very starnge for me also. may be this link haelpfull. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074081/hibernate-error-org-hibernate-nonuniqueobjectexception-a-different-object-with

Answer (score 0):

In my case a had a manyToMany realtionship between A and B and on the equals() method of A the comparison between A.b and otherA.b cause this. I identified the cause but I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

In My Case, I was deleting and updating objects in the same transaction. I was deleting the objects first and then updating. This resulted in the exception. 
To solve the exception, I just changed the order of updating first and then deleting unreferenced objects.