# Spring JPA - A different object with the same identifier value was already

Tags: spring, jpa

I have 3 classes :

```
@Entity
public class Purchase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id ;
    private String description ;
    private  float discount ; //percentage

    private  boolean status ; // paid or not

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private  Company company ;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BusinnesPartner_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private BusineesPartner busineesPartner ;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "purchase", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<PurchaseItem> purchaseItems;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public float getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(float discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public BusineesPartner getBusineesPartner() {
        return busineesPartner;
    }

    public void setBusineesPartner(BusineesPartner busineesPartner) {
        this.busineesPartner = busineesPartner;
    }

    public Set<PurchaseItem> getPurchaseItems() {
        return purchaseItems;
    }

    public void setPurchaseItems(Set<PurchaseItem> purchaseItems) {
        this.purchaseItems = purchaseItems;
    }

    public Purchase() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Purchase [id=" + id + ", description=" + description + ", discount=" + discount + ", status=" + status
                + ", company=" + company + ", busineesPartner=" + busineesPartner + ", purchaseItems=" + purchaseItems
                + "]";
    }
```

}

And item :

```
@Entity
public class Item {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id ;
private String name ;
private String brand ;
private String category ;
private Double unitPrice ;
private Double weight ;
private String manufacturer ;
private String description ;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
private Company company ;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
private Set<ItemInventory> itemInventories;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
private Set<PurchaseItem> purchaseItems;



public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
}

public void setBrand(String brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public Double getUnitPrice() {
    return unitPrice;
}

public void setUnitPrice(Double unitPrice) {
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
}

public Double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(Double weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public String getManufacturer() {
    return manufacturer;
}

public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}




public Set<ItemInventory> getItemInventories() {
    return itemInventories;
}

public void setItemInventories(Set<ItemInventory> itemInventories) {
    this.itemInventories = itemInventories;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Item [id=" + id + "]";
}


public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(Company company) {
    this.company = company;
}



public Set<PurchaseItem> getPurchaseItems() {
    return purchaseItems;
}

public void setPurchaseItem(Set<PurchaseItem> purchaseItems) {
    this.purchaseItems = purchaseItems;
}




public Item(Integer id, String name, String brand, String category, Double unitPrice, Double weight,
        String manufacturer, String description, Company company, Set<ItemInventory> itemInventories,
        Set<PurchaseItem> purchaseItems) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.category = category;
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.description = description;
    this.company = company;
    this.itemInventories = itemInventories;
    this.purchaseItems = purchaseItems;
}

public Item() {
}




}
```

And PurchaseItem :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchase_item")

public class PurchaseItem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")

    private Item item ;



    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "purchase_id")

    private Purchase purchase ;


    private Long quantity ;


    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }


    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }


    public Purchase getPurchase() {
        return purchase;
    }


    public void setPurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        this.purchase = purchase;
    }


    public Long getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }


    public void setQuantity(Long quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }


    public PurchaseItem(Item item, Purchase purchase, Long quantity) {
        super();
        this.item = item;
        this.purchase = purchase;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }


    public PurchaseItem() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PurchaseItem [item=" + item + ", purchase=" + purchase + ", quantity=" + quantity + "]";
    }





}
```

And here is my controller :

```
@RestController
public class PurchaseController {
    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepos ;
    @Autowired
    private InventoryRepository inventoryRepos ;
    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepos ;
    @Autowired
    private PurchaseRepository purchaseRepos ;
    @RequestMapping(value = "purchase/add/{company}", method = RequestMethod.POST)

        public Object addItem(@RequestBody Purchase purchase)  {

        Purchase newPurchase = new Purchase() ;
        newPurchase.setDiscount(purchase.getDiscount());
        newPurchase.setStatus(purchase.isStatus());
        newPurchase.setBusineesPartner(purchase.getBusineesPartner()) ;
        newPurchase.setDescription(purchase.getDescription()) ;
        newPurchase.setPurchaseItems(new HashSet<PurchaseItem>());
        newPurchase = purchaseRepos.save(newPurchase) ;



        for(PurchaseItem curentPurchaseItem : purchase.getPurchaseItems()) {

        Item item = itemRepos.findOne(curentPurchaseItem.getItem().getId()) ;   
        curentPurchaseItem.setPurchase(newPurchase);
        curentPurchaseItem.setItem(item);   

        newPurchase.getPurchaseItems().add(curentPurchaseItem) ;

        }

        return purchaseRepos.save(newPurchase) ;


          }





}
```

Here is the error Stack :

> A different object with the same identifier value was already
>   associated with the session :
>   [com.inconso.models.PurchaseItem#PurchaseItem [item=null,
>   purchase=null, quantity=25]]; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the
>   same identifier value was already associated with the session :
>   [com.inconso.models.PurchaseItem#PurchaseItem [item=null,
>   purchase=null, quantity=25]]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Error: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246675/hibernate-error-a-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-a)