# How to map existing user roles to custom user storage provider in keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, keycloak

I have simple spring boot app which use keycloak SSO with custom user storage provider.
Authentication is work fine without user roles.
But i need to know how to map existing user roles with custom user storage provider.
Does anyone know how to map existing user roles with keycloak user storage provider?

Answer (score 11):

Finally found a way to map roles.

Add roles to realm and override the AbstractUserAdapterFederatedStorage.getRoleMappingsgetRoleMappings() method.

```
public Set<RoleModel> getRoleMappings() {
    Set<RoleModel> roles = new HashSet();
    Iterator rolesItr = userEntity.getRoles().iterator();

    while(rolesItr.hasNext()) {
        roles.add(realm.getRole(((Role)rolesItr.next()).getName()));
    }
    return roles;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a [user storage SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#provider-interfaces) you'll most likely need to implement the UserLookupProvider interface (`org.keycloak.storage.user.UserLookupProvider`).

For instance one of the method in that interface is `UserModel getUserByUsername(String username, RealmModel realm)`

As you can see, the methods in that interface return a `UserModel` object.

`UserModel` implements the `RoleMapperModel` interface. You just have to call the UserModel::grantRole method and pass the roles you want.

Example:

Assuming you have a `class MyUserDao {...}` that retrieves users from your database as a `class MyUserModel {...}` instance.

```java
    public UserModel getUserByUsername(String username, RealmModel realm) {
        Optional<MyUserModel> myUserOpt = myUserDao.getUserByUsername(username);
        if (!myUserOpt.isPresent()) 
           throw new AccessDeniedException();
    
        MyUserModel myUser = myUserOpt .get();
    
        UserModel keycloakUser = mapToKeycloakUserModel(myUser);
    
        for (String roleName: myUser.getRoles())
           userModel.grantRole(KeycloakModelUtils.getRoleFromString(realm, roleName));
        
        return keycloakUser;
    }

    private UserModel mapToKeycloakUserModel(MyUserModel myUser) {...}
```

Note you have to load roles with org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils::getRoleFromString otherwise UserModel::grantRole will try to re-create them and you'll end up with an exception.

Comment: Thanks @otonglet for the answer. The problem is mapping MyRoleModel to RoleModel. Let say MyRoleModel is only have id and name. In that case keycloak's RoleModel interface is bit complex.

Comment: When i get role from ClientModel and do the grantRole() below error was given...
"A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"

Comment: @lakshithamadusanka My bad, I lead you to a JPA error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16246858/1722236 org.keycloak.models.jpa.UserAdapter::grantRole is indeed going to create that role entity. I looked up org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.getRoleFromString(realm, roleName) to figure how to load the RoleModel. Your have to call RealmModel::getRole instead. I updated my answer.

Comment: I did the RealmModel::getRole too. But got the same error.

Comment: @lakshithamadusanka Could you try again with org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils::getRoleFromString method instead of RealModel::getRole ?

Comment: @lakshithamadusanka I'm out of suggestion beyond this point. Sorry if this last resort doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for the help @otonglet. I posted my answer bellow.