# Best practice to avoid 'A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session'

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I think it's a common procedure to

- load an entitiy via hibernate
- store it in a session variable
- change properies
- save it later

What is a common practice to avoid the error `A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session` when the current session has already loaded the object under any circumstances?

- Use merge?
- Avoid loading the same object before?
- Flush the hibernate-session and detach the other Instance?
- Retrieve the object from the session an manually copy the changes from the instance in the session?
- Use DTOs and only store the id in the session handler?
- Any other ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate Error: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246675/hibernate-error-a-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-a)

Comment: i know what the problem is, i just want to know if there is a common pattern for webapplications to avoid this problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess best practices are very opinionated. In the end, you have to choose whatever approach works best for your use case. I personally used the following approaches:

- Using `EntityManager.merge` - It works and is simple, but you have to configure `CascadeType.MERGE` properly on associations that you want to merge as well or do individual merges. This might not fit all use cases though and cause lots of updates
- Get current object from session and apply changes - I mostly do this if I want to be in full control of what can change and maybe trigger some other changes when I see some attribute value changed, but it's quite a lot of tedious code to write
- Use DTOs - This is similar to "Get current object from session and apply changes" as you have to somehow map the DTO to the entity

Having said that, I prefer using the DTO approach but with [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which supports dirty tracking to update only what really changed.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

Take a look at the documentation for more information about this: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/entity-view/manual/en_US/#updatable-mappings-basic

The default flush strategy uses DML queries, so there is no interaction with the persistence context/session except for persisting objects, but there is also a entity flush strategy that works by changing altering objects in the persistence context if you need that.