# Hibernate Embedded Composite Key - EntityExistsException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have an entity Rating with an EmbeddedID referring to the composite key RatingKey. A User has a set of many Ratings, and when trying to create a new Rating, add it to the User and save the user, I run into the following error: `javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [samuelb.capripol.Rating#samuelb.capripol.RatingKey@4ad]`

User Entity:

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userID;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Rating> ratings;
```

Rating Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Ratings")
public class Rating {

    @EmbeddedId
    RatingKey id = new RatingKey();

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("userID")
    @JoinColumn(name="userID")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("focusID")
    @JoinColumn(name="focusID")
    private Focus focus;

    private BigDecimal baseRating;
```

RatingKey:

```
@Embeddable
public class RatingKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="userID")
    private Long userID;

    @Column(name="focusID")
    private Long focusID;

    protected RatingKey(){}

    public RatingKey(Long userID, Long focusID) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.focusID = focusID;
    }

    public Long getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Long userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public Long getFocusID() {
        return focusID;
    }

    public void setFocusID(Long focusID) {
        this.focusID = focusID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        RatingKey ratingKey = (RatingKey) o;
        return Objects.equals(userID, ratingKey.userID) &&
                Objects.equals(focusID, ratingKey.focusID);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userID, focusID);
    }
}
```

Saving the User:

```
if(foci != null && rating != null && foci.length == rating.length){
                for(int i = 0; i < rating.length; i++){
                    Focus focus = focusRepository.findByFocusName(foci[i]);
                    Rating newRating = new Rating(user, focus, new BigDecimal(rating[i]));
                    user.addRating(newRating);
                }
            }
            userRepository.save(user);
```

Adding `cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}` to the User's Ratings made no difference.
Hibernate logging:

```
select rating0_.focusID as focusid1_6_0_, rating0_.userID as userid2_6_0_, rating0_.baseRating as baserati3_6_0_ from Ratings rating0_ where rating0_.focusID=? and rating0_.userID=?
Hibernate: select rating0_.focusID as focusid1_6_0_, rating0_.userID as userid2_6_0_, rating0_.baseRating as baserati3_6_0_ from Ratings rating0_ where rating0_.focusID=? and rating0_.userID=?
2020-10-26 16:15:31.533 TRACE 6120 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2020-10-26 16:15:31.533 TRACE 6120 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [null]
```

EDIT: I think whats happening is in my User Entity I am creating Ratings and adding them to User as so:

```
@PostLoad
    public void assignRatings() {
        for(Group group: usersGroups){
            for(Focus focus: group.getFramework().getFrameworkFoci()){
                ratings.add(new Rating(this, focus, BigDecimal.ONE));
            }
        }
    }
```

So when I try edit the baseRating of a Rating it is creating a new Rating with the same key instead of updating the original rating.
I've removed `cascade` from User and added `@GeneratedValue` to Rating id (also removing the instantiation of the RatingKey) however I now run into the error: `EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find samuelb.capripol.Rating with id samuelb.capripol.RatingKey@3c1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate Error: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246675/hibernate-error-a-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-a)

Comment: Unfortunately not, however I think the issues are similar