# org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: exception occurs when calling Hibernate saveorUpdate()

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate

This is the piece of code from my program,in which I have tried to insert into Question table with hibernate `saveOrUpdae()` method.

```
this.txTemplate.setReadOnly(false);
this.txTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        this.txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status)
        {
             questionManager.saveQuestionsofCurrentUser(filteredStreamDataMapForCurrentUSer.values(),user);
                 questionManager.updateQuestionsReady1on2(user);  

        }
});
```

When try to run with multiple users, I am getting **`org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException:`**.The process run using multi thread concept.Any one can suggest a solution for it?

Comment: have you tried auto-increment option?

Comment: primary key is not auto incremented one it is aaigned from our code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate Error: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074081/hibernate-error-org-hibernate-nonuniqueobjectexception-a-different-object-with)

Comment: Have you printed out the primary keys of the objects before calling saveOrUpdate?  Are you sure you don't have two objects with the same primary key?