# hibernate NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

My Code:

I am trying to do either update/insert. It gets inserted properly, only problem is when I try to update it gives below error message.

```
private String sessionType=null;
public String getAccountsDetails(List<Account> accountList) {       
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    for (Account account : accountList) {
        AccountDetails accountDetails = new AccountDetails();
        accountDetails.setAccountsId(Long.parseLong(account.getId()));
        accountDetails.setAccounttype(account.getAccountType().value());
        Query query = session.createQuery("from QBAccounts qba where qba.accountsId=:accId");
        List<AccountDetails> queryList = query.setParameter("accId", accountDetails.getAccountsId()).list();
        if(queryList.size()>0){         
            session.update(accountDetails);
        }else{
            session.save(accountDetails);
        }
    }
    session.flush();  
    session.beginTransaction().commit();
    session.clear();
    session.close();           
    return "Successfully data updated into table";
}
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.trinet.mulesoft.quickbooks.dto.AccountDetails#0]
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:638)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:246)
```

---

EDIT 2:

I have used

> session.merge(accountDetails)

there is no error, but it always does insert data into db instead of update.

Comment: Why are you using two different sessions? You can deal with save and update in same session, unless I am missing something. See if this helps http://tech.lalitbhatt.net/2014/07/hibernate-persistent-context-and-session.html

Comment: @lalit, I tried with same session, as I informed, it works fine for insert for the first time, then next step is update, it throws same error. Earlier I was getting stale object state exception, so I used different session. Updated above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Error: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074081/hibernate-error-org-hibernate-nonuniqueobjectexception-a-different-object-with)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public String getAccountsDetails(AccountDetails accountDetails) {
        System.out.println("accountDetails.accoundId-->"+accountDetails.getAccountsId());
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from QBAccounts qba where qba.accountsId=:accId");
        List<AccountDetails> queryList = query.setParameter("accId", accountDetails.getAccountsId()).list();
        session.close();
        Session session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
//          session.saveOrUpdate(accountDetails);
        try{
            if(queryList.size()>0){                 
                session2.beginTransaction();
                /*
                 *  comment below line-50,51 to use update instead of merge, and uncomment line 53
                 */
                AccountDetails acDet = (AccountDetails) session2.get(AccountDetails.class, new Long(1));//line 50
                session2.merge(accountDetails);//line 51
                System.out.println("acDet-->"+acDet+"  --accountDetails->  "+accountDetails);//line 52
//              session2.update(accountDetails);//line 53
            }else{
                session2.beginTransaction();
                session2.save(accountDetails);
            }
        }catch(DIRException e){
            session2.getTransaction().rollback();
            System.out.println("Getting Exception : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }finally{
             session2.getTransaction().commit();
             session2.close();
        }
        return "Successfully data updated into table";
    }
```

Removed @GeneratedValue from my dto, since value was coming from UI.

Here is the good article, how to use [MERGE/UPDATE](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/difference-between-update-and-merge-methods-in-hibernate/)

Comment: link to artricle is dead

Answer (score 7):

I had this error when opening two sessions.
One session for a User and another session for an object that has its primary key a foreign key from User.
With this,the two session has the same primary key or identifier.
I solved this by session.clear before session.update(type).

```
public T update(T type) {
        Session session = getSession();
        session.clear();
        session.update( type );
        session.flush();
        return type;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using one session only as suggested by lalit.

The code reduced to as below.

```
private String sessionType=null;
public String getAccountsDetails(List<Account> accountList) {       
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    for (Account account : accountList) {
        AccountDetails accountDetails = new AccountDetails();
        accountDetails.setAccountsId(Long.parseLong(account.getId()));
        accountDetails.setAccounttype(account.getAccountType().value());
        Query query = session.createQuery("from QBAccounts qba where qba.accountsId=:accId");
        List<AccountDetails> queryList = query.setParameter("accId", accountDetails.getAccountsId()).list();
        if(queryList.size()>0){         
            session.update(accountDetails);
            sessionType = "update";
        }else{
            session.save(accountDetails);
            sessionType = "save";
        }
    }
        session.flush();  
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
        session.clear();
        session.close();


    return "Successfully data updated into table";
}
```

Comment: I tried with same session, as I informed, it works fine for insert for the first time, then next step is update, it throws same error. Earlier I was getting stale object state exception, so I used different session.

Answer (score 1):

Quite late reply but others who are searching for the same error can know. This worked for me. When you are saving data in a loop before commit use session.flush() and after commit use session.clear().

```
    session.flush();
    session.beginTransaction().commit();
    session.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the PK of your Account Details entity ? is it AccountsId ?

You've fetched Accounts details from database to your current hibernate session.

```
    Query query = session.createQuery("from QBAccounts qba where qba.accountsId=:accId");
    List<AccountDetails> queryList = query.setParameter("accId", accountDetails.getAccountsId()).list();
```

When you are saving

```
    session.save(accountDetails);
```

accountDetails pass from transient state to persisted state, and then managed by current session, but you've already have an object with same ID in your session due to accounts details fetching before, so hibernate session got confused.

When you are using merge, hibernate will synchronize the states of existing in-session object with your new object which is accountDetails.