# save primary object with child object gives error while save using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have created entity bean as Company which has `@ManyToOne` relationship with User. how can we achieve using hibernate.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="company_details")
public class Company implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String nameOfCompany;
    private User createdBy;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id", nullable=false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="NAME_OF_COMPANY", nullable=false)
    public String getNameOfCompany() {
        return nameOfCompany;
    }
    public void setNameOfCompany(String nameOfCompany) {
        this.nameOfCompany = nameOfCompany;
    }
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    public User getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(User users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

while i am saving company object, hibernate throws below exception:

> org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the
>   same identifier value was already associated with the session:
>   [com.myProject.models.User#23]

Save code as below:

```
Company company = new Company();
company.setNameOfCompany("my comp");
User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
com.myProject.models.User userDetails = userProfileService.getUserInfoByUserName(user.getUsername());
customer.setUsers(userDetails);
Long id = companyService.save(company);
```

DAO:

```
public Long save(Company comp) throws Exception {
         sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(comp);
        return comp.getId();
    }
```

I already gone through [Hibernate Error: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074081/hibernate-error-org-hibernate-nonuniqueobjectexception-a-different-object-with) post but it seams not useful for me.

Comment: can you share your User class?

Comment: Please check if(user.getUserId()==userDetails.getUserId()) is returning true (in case both the User class is same in your code). If yes, then this is where the problem exists.

Comment: Also , you should share the required info while asking questions. No one is going to hit the fish eye without any hint of what and where.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are assigning `@ManyToOne` Mapping and passing only single object.

So change `Model` mapping with

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
List<User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
```

Now when you are saving company entity then pass List of users to `setUsers` method