# Can I save one object twice in a same transaction,using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Same as the title says. I met the problem. I begin a transaction and save an object twice, then I get this exception:

```
 "org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException"
```

And the object is not selected from db.the first save means "insert into", the second save means "update".

Comment: I find the answer [Hibernate Error: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074081/hibernate-error-org-hibernate-nonuniqueobjectexception-a-different-object-with)

Comment: Yeah, save() is for inserting. The javadoc says: *Persist the given **transient** instance*. Once saved, the entity becomes *attached*, and any change you make is **transparently, automatically** made persistent. Read the user guide. This is critical stuff.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks , got it.