# Hibernate NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm getting **NonUniqueObjectException** in hibernate.

There is one Item class, I saved list of Item objects using `session.save` of hibernate.

Now in the same transaction, I'm trying to update same Items using raw sql query which has join with another table. This gives me NonUniqueObjectException. The two tables I'm joining are unrelated as entities for hibernate, that is, there is no foreign key relation.

So I have 2 questions:

> - First, is there any way of using hql for writing inner join queries in hibernate.
> - Second, how to avoid NonUniqueObjectException.

Comment: please add your transactional method.. with the queries

Comment: Refer https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html for inner join (Chapter 14).

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074081/hibernate-error-org-hibernate-nonuniqueobjectexception-a-different-object-with, some possible reasons for NonUniqueObjectException

Comment: @MaciejKowalski - please see the code snippet

String sql = "UPDATE Item INNER JOIN BinItem " +
                "ON Item.itemId = BinItem.itemId " +
                "SET Item.itemStatus = :itemStatusParam " +
                "WHERE BinItem.binId = :binIdParam";
        Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter("itemStatusParam", status.toString());
        query.setParameter("binIdParam", binId);
        return query.executeUpdate();

Comment: @user1211 - doesn't help since the entities are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that is working is that I clear the session before making any raw sql query. Any better approach is welcomed.