# Error : org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: hibernate

I have an object is loaded in the hibernate session and not modified, and I get this error when the object is loaded again and deleted. I thought that if the object had been modified the first time, any further change would give this error but that isn't the case for me.

I saw the related question [Hibernate Error: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074081/hibernate-error-org-hibernate-nonuniqueobjectexception-a-different-object-with?rq=1) but it's not clear whether this error is thrown even if the first object in the session is not modified before the second change.